# How to Get only Integer objects, only String Objects, only even Integer objects ....?

Tags: java

Hey guys I am learning and playing with ArrayList, I was able to create a basic ArrayList.
I would like to accomplish the following: I was trying different methods but couldn't get it.

```
        - Get only Integer objects:
        - Get only String Objects
        - Get only even Integer objects
        - Get Integer and Double Objects.
        - Get all String Objects starts with "S".
        - Get all String Objects which contains a.
```

======================= Here is my program =========================

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo1 {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        System.out.println("Before = " + al.size());
        al.add(10);
        al.add(43);
        al.add(32.5);
        al.add(10);
        al.add(null);
        al.add('A');
        al.add("ABC");
        al.add(10.12);
        al.add(true);
        al.add("Hello");
        al.add(600);
        al.add(900);
//        System.out.println(al);
//        System.out.println("After = " + al.size());
//        System.out.println(al instanceof Cloneable); //true
//        System.out.println(al instanceof Serializable); //true
//        System.out.println(al instanceof RandomAccess);
//        System.out.println(al instanceof List);
//        System.out.println(al instanceof Collection);
//        System.out.println(al instanceof Set);
//        ArrayList<Integer> a1 = al;
//        System.out.println(a1);

  
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)), e.g. `al.stream().filter(entry -> …).…`

Comment: Note that you are using a **raw type**. `ArrayList` expects one generic type argument to be given, but you are providing none. This only compiles because of backward-compatibility. You should provide a type argument.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to convert my Arraylist or I can just give the above command, could you give me an examples please, as I am searching online for example....

Comment: @MCEmperor I think I wanted ArrayList to be raw, only then I can extract other type of data like strings,Integer... objects? do I make sense?

Comment: You could declare your list as List<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over each Object using for loop and check if it is an Integer or String. Then you could check for all the sub conditions specified.

```
for (Object obj: al) {
    if (obj instanceof String){
        // this  is string 
    } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
       // this  is Integer 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use instance of to check against the type of the given element. To get the elements of integers for example, try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size() ; i++){
    if(al.get(i) instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

10
43
10
600
900